# Sum values with a check box/radio button

Tags: php, database, sum, html-table

I basically have a database table of values where one of the columns displays the cost of each asset.

I'm trying to add checkboxes to the side of each of the costs, so that I can select the values I want and display the averages and sum.

For Example:

[image]

Comment: Take few minutes and show yur code

Comment: <checkbox name=somename[]> and sum the array values in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is sample **html** and **Js** code that should solve your problem....

**HTML** is blow

```
  <table width="100%" border="1">
            <tr><th>Cost</th><th>Action</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_list" val="30"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_list" val="20"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_list" val="25"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_list" val="35"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td style="text-align: right">Sum</td><td><span id="sum"></span></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="text-align: right">AVG</td><td><span id="avg"></span></td></tr>
        </table>
```

& **JS** is blow

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            update();
        });
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
            update();
        })
        function update(){
            var sum = 0;
            $('.check_list').each(function () {
                if (this.checked) {              
                    sum += Number($(this).attr("val")); 
                }
            });
            $("#sum").html(sum);
            var checkCount = $(".check_list:checked").length;
            $("#avg").html(parseFloat(sum/checkCount).toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>
```

Best of Luck!!

Comment: Thank you so much!. but i am very new to coding. how do i combine both the Js and the html?. i am apologise

Comment: Hi You can get the source code from the git source https://bitbucket.org/jakirhkhan/basichtml/src/a96b95fd6b66257693f76c557d6dd03b7e43885e?at=jakirhkhan/indexphp-created-online-with-bitbucket-1453015858544

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!